# xlwings is it possible to save file as csv?

Tags: python, csv, xlwings

I am searching for this answer for like 2 hours now.

Is it possible to save newly created workbook as csv or csv-utf8 file ???

I know how to save it as xlsx xlsm etc, but csv does not seem to work.

Save part of the Code below:

```
wb = xw.Book()
wb.sheets.add('Ceny')
wb.sheets['Ceny'].range('A1').options(index=False, header=False).value = mainDF
wb.save(r'D:\mainDF.csv')
wb.app.quit()
```

Error I am getting:

```
file_format = ext_to_file_format[target_ext]
KeyError: '.csv'
```

I was reading that I am supposed to sepcify file format and maybe use saveas ?? but I have no idea how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this but it's a bit messy - when you run this code an instance of Excel will pop-up.

Also, as far as I know, it's OS specific for Windows.

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings.constants import FileFormat

mainDF = pd.DataFrame({'Field1':[1,2,3,4], 'Field2':['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})

with xw.App() as app:
    wb = app.books.add()
    wb.sheets.add('Ceny')
    wb.sheets['Ceny'].range('A1').options(index=False, header=False).value = mainDF
    wb.api.SaveAs(r'C:\Test\PythonExamples\mainDF.csv', FileFormat:=FileFormat.xlCSV)
```

Comment: Used only last line of Your code and it seems to work (does not open any extra excel instances). Thank You for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's currently not supported as I had some issues with the implementation on macOS. What works though would be to use the Python tools to do it, something like this:

```py
import xlwings as xw
import csv

sheet = xw.books.active.sheets.active

with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(sheet.used_range.value)
```

Comment: Seems to work too tho it requires other libraries. Thank You for an answer and help. Btw do You plan on adding that to xlwings anytime soon ?

Comment: `csv` is part of the standard library. And feel free to open an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

It seems no direct method to save sheet as csv file.
Other methods to iterate each row in range are too slow or unstable.
If we use clipboard, the process is much fast and reliable.

```
#dependency
import pyperclip
import xlwings as xw

    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    sht=wb["sheetname"]

#copy selected data to clipboard first
    real_range = sht["A1"].expand()
    real_range.clear_formats()
    real_range.select()
    real_range.copy()

#use clipboard data
    csv_data = pyperclip.paste()
    
    with open(OutputCsvFile, 'w') as file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
        for row in csv_data.split("\n"):
            csv_writer.writerow(row.split("\t"))

    print("%s output successfully!\n" % OutputCsvFile)
```